# Nuitka doesn't get along with PySimpleGUI: `CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS14' error

Tags: python, pysimplegui, nuitka

I try to make an EXE on windows with Nuitka but always get error like this: CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS14

I googled 'CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS14' but nothing shows up. Does anyone have similar issue?

I am using Python 3.9 and 3.10 and this is my command

```
nuitka --standalone --onefile --mingw64 --show-memory --show-progress --follow-imports --output-dir=out Demo_Hello_World.py
```

The Demo_Hello_World.py is from PySimpleGUI/DemoPrograms/Demo_Hello_World.py

```
     ValueTraceLoopComplete 38798 30843 7955
     ValueTraceLoopIncomplete 16811 14635 2176
     ValueTraceMerge 470835 399699 71136
     ValueTraceUninitialized 82073 66112 15961
     ValueTraceUnknown 238500 209701 28799
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: gcc (gcc).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend linking program with 14 modules (no progress information available).
module.PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.c: In function 'impl_PySimpleGUI$PySimpleGUI$$$function__578__github_issue_post_make_markdown':
module.PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.c:549680:35: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS14'; did you mean 'CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS10'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
549680 |             tmp_assign_source_2 = CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS14(unicode_builtin_format, args);
       |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       |                                   CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS10
module.PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.c:549680:33: warning: assignment to 'PyObject *' {aka 'struct _object *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
549680 |             tmp_assign_source_2 = CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS14(unicode_builtin_format, args);
       |                                 ^

Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Running 'C:\\Users\\nytrg\\AppData\\Local\\Nuitka\\Nuitka\\gcc\\x86_64\\11.3.0-14.0.3-10.0.0-msvcrt-r3\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe -o "F:\\PySimpleGUI\\DemoPrograms\\out\\Demo_Hello_World.dist\\Demo_Hello_World.exe" -fuse-linker-plugin -flto=6 -fpartial-inlining -freorder-functions -Wl,--exclude-all-symbols -Wl,--out-implib,.\\import.lib -municode -O3 -s -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--stack,9863168 -static-libgcc @".\\@link_input.txt" -LC:\\Users\\nytrg\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs -lm -lpython39' took 164.76 seconds
c:/users/nytrg/appdata/local/nuitka/nuitka/gcc/x86_64/11.3.0-14.0.3-10.0.0-msvcrt-r3/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\nytrg\AppData\Local\Temp\cccIcn6f.ltrans80.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x32b8): undefined reference to `CALL_FUNCTION_WITH_ARGS14'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

scons: *** [F:\PySimpleGUI\DemoPrograms\out\Demo_Hello_World.dist\Demo_Hello_World.exe] Error 1
```

Comment: Did any of the Issues in the Nuitka repo that discuss using PySimpleGUI with Nuitka help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only thing that helped me was compiling in a clean Python venv, the issue may be due to some package conflict but requires further investigation.

So to sum that up:

1. Create a clean [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
2. Activate the venv using the appropriate script (Refer to the table below)
   [image: Activate script table]
3. Install just the necessary prerequisites through pip (including Nuitka of course)
4. Try compiling with nuitka again

Answer (score 0):

My application, [WSA Sideloader](https://github.com/infinitepower18/WSA-Sideloader) is a PySimpleGUI program compiled using Nuitka. This is the command I used:

```
nuitka --standalone sideloader.py --enable-plugin=tk-inter --windows-disable-console
```

Of course the name of your main Python file should be used after --standalone.

Note that if it requires other files to function you will need to add them to the dist folder once it's compiled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).